# How to display data from mysql into ckeditor field using angularjs php?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ckeditor

I want to display data from mysql into ckeditor field using angularjs, it works. But the only problem is the array also displayed [(can refer here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrDvK.png)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [qterm] =>This paragraph only.) )
```

here is my coding.

*index.html*

`<textarea name="editor1" class="ckeditor" id="editor1" ng-model="tnc"></textarea>`

*myApp.js*

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('cntrl', function($scope,$http) {

    function getTerm() {
        $http.get("qterm.php").success(function(data) {
            $scope.tnc = data;
        });
    };
    getTerm();
});
```

*qterm.php*

```
<?php
include('../config.php');
$query="select qterm from configuration";
$data = array();
$rs=$connect->query($query);

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $data[] = $result;
}

print_r($data);
//print json_encode($data);
?>
```

What should I do? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = print_r($data, true);
echo $output;
```